# Questions regarding third party services?

Tags: discussion

I am wondering if it is still within the topic to ask questions regarding third-party services of the tezos ecosystem ?

For example there is a tool bakers use to monitor and advertise their performance metrics called « mytezosbaker ». Some questions relate to how precisely those metrics are calculated. Would that be fair to ask on TSE or off-topic ?

This will likely come-up once we get public so would be great to setup our mind first on this.